# Ruby Output Kramdown to Text/Kramdown

Tags: html, ruby, kramdown

I'm looking for a way to translate an `html` file to a `Markdown` type syntax.  That's the request from my client.  They think that this type of archival method is good for manipulation into one of their GUI apps, while maintaining the ability to edit with an acceptable amount of retained markup.

I'm looking at `Kramdown`, but it's confusing.  I have created a `Kramdown` object imported from the `html` file:

```
doc = Kramdown::Document.new(source, :input => 'html')
```

I'd like to output the `Kramdown` format, but I don't understand how to save it as a `Kramdown` format.

Is there a way to save the file with the `Kramdown` format?  The original `html` file is parsed into `Kramdown`, now I want to save that file much like how I would a `Markdown` file, with that simple markup syntax.  This works just fine:

```
puts doc.to_html
```

...so `doc` is just fine. I just need a way to output the `Kramdown` version.  Any insight appreciated.  Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `to_kramdown` method. It’s not documented directly as it is dynamically called, but see [`method_missing`](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/rdoc/Kramdown/Document.html#method-i-method_missing).

```
doc = Kramdown::Document.new(source, :input => 'html')
puts doc.to_kramdown
```

Comment: OK, thank you, that works.  I thought the doc object was indeed a `kramdown` object already.  Shouldn't it have a method such as `inspect`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://github.com/xijo/reverse_markdown:

```
input  = '<strong>feelings</strong>'
result = ReverseMarkdown.convert input
result.inspect # " **feelings** "
```

Comment: Yes I tried that gem and it didn't convert a single thing, which is why I moved to `Kramdown`.  Not really sure what happened there.